# Summation and minimal value function

Tags: summation

I am working on a summation problem that is asking me to find the sum of an expression with the minimum value function in the exponent. I'm  not sure about the rules when working with sums and min-function so some of you might enlighten me.

$
\sum_{x=0}^{76}{p(x)(1/1.03)^{\min(X,34)+1}} =
 \sum_{x=0}^{33}{p(x)(1/1.03)^{x+1}}  
+\sum_{x=34}^{76}{p(x)(1/1.03)^{34+1}}
$

Can someone explain the above equation and why it is true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of min(x, 34) = x for $1 \leq x \leq 33$, since x $<$ 34.

The value of min(x, 34) = 34 for $34 \leq x \leq 76$, since x $\geq$ 34. So the sum should be,
$$\sum_{x=0}^{76}p(x)\left( \frac{1}{1.03} \right)^{min(x, 34) + 1}$$
$$= \sum_{x=0}^{33}p(x)\left( \frac{1}{1.03} \right)^{min(x, 34)  + 1} +
    \sum_{x=34}^{76}p(x)\left( \frac{1}{1.03} \right)^{min(x, 34) + 1}  $$
Since min(x, 34) = x for $1 \leq x \leq 33$, substitute this value into the first sum.
Similarly, since min(x, 34) = 34 for  x $\geq$ 34, substitute this value into the second sum.
$$= \sum_{x=0}^{33}p(x)\left( \frac{1}{1.03} \right)^{x + 1} +
    \sum_{x=34}^{76}p(x)\left( \frac{1}{1.03} \right)^{34+ 1}  $$